# Live Droppable UI Element Only Accepts Drop on Second Try

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have JQuery UI Droppables that are dynamically added to the page via Ajax.  Attempting to follow the guidance to connect the Droppables in a live manner:

[jQuery UI Droppable : how to make it live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978460/jquery-ui-droppable-how-to-make-it-live/6866437#6866437)

On the first attempt to drag-and-drop, the `hoverClass` is not hooked up nor is the drop target a registered `Droppable` (the drop event handler does not fire).  On subsequent attempts, it works as expected.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/ESCN9/

How can I get the drop functionality to work the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works only when you hover on the "ctFilterDropArea" element and which initiates the live droppable functionality.

Try starting your liveDroppable implementation once the another div is dragged.

JSFiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/ESCN9/3/

```
$.fn.liveDroppable = function (opts) {
    if (!$(this).data("ctDropInit")) {
        $(this).data("ctDropInit", true).droppable(opts);
    }
};

$('#dragMe').draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    distance: 20,
    opacity: 0.7,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: startDroppable
});

function startDroppable() {
    $('#ctFilterDropArea').liveDroppable({
        hoverClass: "ctDropHover",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("Dropped!");
        }
    });
}
```