# Make a class sortable with other classes named the same, only if they are siblings w/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

### Clarification:

I am trying to make the portlets sortable, but trying to connect them with any columns that are siblings

---

I would like my web-application to automatically apply the [`jquery ui`](http://jqueryui.com)  [`sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/1.) interaction to all divs with the class `.column`.

There are two little tricks that I need in this solution, no its not as simple as `$(".column").sortable()`...

1. *I need the columns to `connectWith` any other columns that are siblings*
2. *I would* like *the solution to apply to any `.column` elements that are dynamically generated, i've been looking for something similar to my new favorite toy, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), to no avail... although a custom event to detect a `.column` element creation might work, not sure how to do that though.*

### EX:

*markup*

```
<div id="container1" class="column-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $columns = $(".column");
  $columns.sortable({
    connectWith: $columns.parent().find('.column')  //this untested, but you get the idea... i'll write back with the results of this, might be some good direction
  });
});
```

---

**I would like the columns in `container1` to be sortable with other columns in `container1`, but not `container2`.  Also those in `container2` w/ `container2` but not `container1`.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand this is easier than you are making it.

For the sortable columns within a container, from your markup, the jquery activation would be:

```
$('.column-container').sortable();
```

The selector you currently have on your sortable would actually make the portlets sortable.

As for the live events, refer to this earlier question:
[live drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events)

**EDIT**:

After your comment, the selector would be:

```
$('.column-container').sortable({items: '.portlet'});
```

**EDIT 2:**
Since it is still not working here is the full example:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .column-container { width: 100%; }
        .column-container .column { float: left; width: 100px; background: #ccc; margin-left: 10px; }
        .column-container .column .portlet { border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.column-container').sortable({items: '.portlet'});
        });
    </script>
    <div id="container1" class="column-container">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[0] .portlet[0]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[0] .portlet[1]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[0] .portlet[2]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[1] .portlet[0]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[1] .portlet[1]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[1] .portlet[2]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[2] .portlet[0]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[2] .portlet[1]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container1 .column[2] .portlet[2]</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div><br />
    <div id="container2" class="column-container">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[0] .portlet[0]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[0] .portlet[1]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[0] .portlet[2]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[1] .portlet[0]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[1] .portlet[1]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[1] .portlet[2]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[2] .portlet[0]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[2] .portlet[1]</div>
            <div class="portlet">#container2 .column[2] .portlet[2]</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: excuse me for the confusion... I am trying to make the portlets sortable, but trying to connect them with any columns that are siblings

Comment: hmmm. very odd. your example works, but not in the application.  Must be some kind of conflict...

Comment: probably a contextual issue... I'll look into it later. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works when applying an ID to the parent, i'll see if i can't rig up a more flexible solution.

### markup:

```
<div id="container1" class="column-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
    <div class="portlet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### javascript:

```
//connects with `#container1 .column` and `#container2 .column`
$('.column').sortable({
  connectWith: $(this).parent().attr('id') + ' .column'
});
```

### Paired With

This live jquery draggable extension found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210?tab=votes#tab-top)

```
(function ($) {
   jQuery.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
      this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
         }
      });
   };
})(jQuery);
```