# jQuery Drag and Drop Breaks When Loading Divs by AJAX

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a list of draggables that need to be dropped onto divs loaded by AJAX. However, when the divs are loaded by AJAX it breaks the droppables functionality. I removed AJAX from the equation and it worked fine.

Here's working code. With this code I can drag items in my .contentList to #block1 div and everything works peachy.

```
<div id="block1"></div>

$(".contentList").draggable();

var dropOpts = {
  hoverClass: "activated",
  tolerance: "pointer",
  drop: getURL
};

$("#block1").droppable(dropOpts);
```

I then have the following code load a new div via jQuery .load.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#template1").click(function() {
        $("#dynamic-ui").load("/templates/newtemplate.html");
    });
```

The newtemplate.html contains a div with the same id; #block1. However, once it loads I can no longer drag onto it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code to make #block1 droppable after the newtemplate.html is loaded into dom. e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#template1").click(function() {
        $("#dynamic-ui").load("/templates/newtemplate.html");
        var dropOpts = {
            hoverClass: "activated",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            drop: getURL
        };

        $("#block1").droppable(dropOpts);        
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm. That didn't work for me. I'm playing around with the concept, and with live.

Comment: Success! All I had to do was wrap your code in the .load call back function, and presto, working code. Good way to start the morning. I updated Rohit's code to reflect the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The binding of events happens when the browser loads the webpage.
So during the loading if the JavaScript didn't find the specified division/element they won't bind the event. So for dynamically created divisions you need use [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind the events.

For your question i think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events) will answer you.

Hope it will help you.
Good luck