# Extending jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to add some existing functionality to a site that uses `jQuery` (I want to get the `draggable` feature working with `live()`).

I found a bit of code which does it but I am having trouble getting it to work.

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
      this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
         }
      });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

I added the code after I have loaded `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` and before I actually do anything with it, however, when I try to use it, I get the following error:

```
$('.myclass').liveDraggable({}) is undefined.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `$('.myclass').liveDraggable({})` is `undefined` because you don't return anything.

Comment: Are your sure it's `liveDraggable` which it says is undefined?  I assume you're including jQuery UI after jQuery core?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question to clarify

Comment: @Rocket - true, the function should be defined and callable, but it is not adhering to proper plugin practices by returning the collection n order for chaining. @Dan - are you trying to chain something off of the call to `liveDraggable`?

Comment: Yes, a call to droppable

Comment: @Rocket, adding a return fixed the problem.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine.  `$('.myclass').liveDraggable({})` is going to return `undefined` because there is no return statement.  Usually, you want to `return this` so you can chain calls.

```
(function ($) { 
   $.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
      return this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
         }
      });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Now you can chain this with other jQuery methods.

```
$('.myclass').liveDraggable({}).live('click', function(){
  // code
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to include the jQuery UI script(s) for this to work (not just core jQuery), also see [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Also it looks like that piece of code originated from this SO thread which has some usage examples as well: [jQuery Drag And Drop Using Live Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events)