# jquery drag elements sent by a controller

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm working on a MVC application, containing a search input. The controller sends to the view a list of items that start with the letters present in the input.

My problem is that I want this received items (with the class `.suggest`) to be draggable, with a clone helper. If I use the following code in the `$(document).ready` function

```
$(".suggest").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

the items are not draggable. I suppose this is because the items have been loaded after the page loading?

If I add the class `.ui-draggable` in the HTML code of the items, it doesn't work neither.
Is there a solution to drag elements loaded by a controller?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)?

Comment: Did you include the correct libraries?

Comment: Yes, the correct libraries are included : if I try this code on items that are loaded at the beginning, it works..

Comment: `$(document).ready` will fire exactly one time. You'll need to use `draggable` on your elements *after* they have been loaded. You'll have to include a part from the controller code, namely the creation and append of the `.suggest` elements in order to get satisfying answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've included a function $(document).ready in the message sent to the view, and it works. But is it a good way to make the message longer between the controller and the view ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this topic:

[jQuery Drag And Drop Using Live Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events)

Comment: I found an other solution : when I receive the information from the controller, I call a javascript function that sets the draggable attribute, and the helper function.