# How to make all div draggable with in a parent container

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery

There is a `div` with id `parentDiv`, and there are some div with class `block1` in `parentDiv` divl

like

```
<div id="btn"><input name="click" type="button" value="Click" class='button" /></div>

<div id="parentDiv">
    <div class="block1" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:orange;">I am Block1</div>
    <div class="block1" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:orange;">I am Block1</div>
</div>
```

and In JQuery, div with class `block1`, are draggable.

```
$(function(){
    $('.block1').draggable({
        drag: function() {
           $('.block1').text('Drag Now!');
        },
        stop: function() {
           $('.block1').text('Stop Now!');
        }
    });
});
```

These div are working as aspect, but the problem is, if any new div with `block1` is appended in the `parentDiv` by clicking on btn input like

```
$('#btn').on('click', 'input.button', function(){
    var $newDiv=$('<div class="block1" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:green;">I am Block1</div>');
});
```

that is not draggable.

Yes, It will not work, because it was not in DOM.

We are able to define a `click` event on `#btn` div to its children `input.button`, and if we add new input with class button in this `#btn` div, all will work as aspect.

So my question is, Is there a way to make all div draggable with in a parent container `parentDiv`, like we can do with `#btn` div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "live" function of jquery to add events and functions on future elements.

This code is borrowed from another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805210/jquery-drag-and-drop-using-live-events)

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
      this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
         }
      });
      return $();
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Now instead of calling it like:

```
$(selector).draggable({opts});
```

...just use:

```
$(selector).liveDraggable({opts})
```

Comment: Yes, It is working. but as jquery doc says that live() method is deprecated. How can we use it with using live.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [jQuery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the `mouseover` event to bind uninitialized draggable children:

```
$(".parentDiv").on("mouseover", ".block1", function() {

    // Use the UI pseudo-selector to check that
    // it is not already draggable
    if(!$(this).is(":ui-draggable"))
        $(this).draggable({
            /* Options */
        });
});
```

For convenience, wrapped in a function that extends jQuery:

```
$.fn.extend({

    /**
     * Children of the element with the given selector
     * will automatically be made draggable
     * @param {String} selector
     *  The selector of the child / descendant elements
     *  to automatically be made draggable
     * @param {Object} opts
     *  The options that would normally be passed to the
     *  draggable method
     * @returns
     *  The jQuery array for chaining
     */
    draggableChildren: function(selector, opts) {

        // On using event delegation to automatically
        // handle new child events
        $(this).on("mouseover", selector, function() {

           // Check that draggable not already initialized
           if(!$(this).is(":ui-draggable"))

               // Initialize draggable
               $(this).draggable(opts);
        });

        // Return this for chaining
        return this;
    }
});
```

You can use this as follows:

```
$(".parentDiv").draggableChildren(".block1", {
    drag: function() {
        $(this).text('Drag Now!');
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).text('Stop Now!');
    }
});
```

[**Here is a fiddle showing it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/X9TnW/)

Comment: Thanks a lot of this! +100 if I could. I made also a .resizable version of this. This technique allowed me to reduce .draggable and .resizable creation time of 260 divs from 2600 ms to 20 ms, because .d and .r are now initialized only when needed. And what the best: this have to be done only once per page load.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `containment` property to parent to restrict the area.

```
$("#yourItem" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

To enable draggable for the new dynamic item, what you can do is, move the code which binds the draggablity feature to a method and call that method after you add new item to the DOM

```
 function BindDraggable()
 {
    $('.block1').draggable({
        drag: function() {
           $('.block1').text('Drag Now!');
        },
        stop: function() {
           $('.block1').text('Stop Now!');
        },
        containment: 'parent'
    });
 }
```

Now call it on document ready and soon after you add new content

```
$(function(){
  BindDraggable();

  $('#btn').on('click', 'input#button', function(){
    var $newDiv=$('<div class="block1" style=" width:100px; height:100px; background:green;">I am Block1</div>');
    //to do :attach the new item to the DOM

    BindDraggable();
});
```

});

Comment: Yes, Currently I am using as you describe, But Is there any way to only call this BindDraggable() once, and It work for new once.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#maindiv div").draggable({container:"#maindiv",scroll:false})
```

and now you can do what ever you want

Comment: There is no `container` option in draggable object as far as I know. Did you mean `containment`..?