# Draggable UI - How to define undraggable area?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working on a draggable functionality. In that I have created an area (See attached Screenshot) in which I have to drag the images. But there is also one undraggable area in which I have to disable the draggable functionality.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/nl43fu

```
+-------+
|       |
|   D   |
|       |
|   +---+
|   |   |
|   | U |
|   |   |
+---+---+
```

D = Draggable, U = Undraggable

It would be great if someone can help on this issue. Your help might be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Draggable containment uses the Box Model to identify boundaries for draggable items.

> **containment** Type: Selector or Element or String or Array, Default: false
>
> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region. **Multiple types supported:**
>
> - **Selector:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.
> - **Element:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
> - **String:** Possible values: `"parent"`, `"document"`, `"window"`.
> - **Array:** An array defining a bounding box in the form `[ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]`.

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

So this means you need to create either complex boxes or build collision detection into your `drag` callback. When `drag` is triggered, it is passed an `event` and `ui` object. `ui.position` can be manipulated:

> Current CSS position of the helper as `{ top, left }` object. The values may be changed to modify where the element will be positioned. This is useful for custom containment, snapping, etc.

This can be difficult, so if this is a beggining project or something small, consider using Collision plugin: [jQuery Dragging With Collision Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627860/jquery-dragging-with-collision-detection)

Consider the following primitive example.

```js
$(function() {
  function log(obj) {
    var str = "T: " + obj.top + " L:, " + obj.left + ", R: " + obj.right + ", B: " + obj.bottom;
    $("#log").html(str);
  }

  function getObjectPos(obj) {
    var oPos = obj.position();
    oPos.right = oPos.left + obj.width();
    oPos.bottom = oPos.top + obj.height();
    return oPos;
  }

  function collision(a, b) {
    var col = false;
    var side;
    var r1 = getObjectPos(a);
    var r2 = getObjectPos(b);
    /*
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection
    rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x && rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y
   */
    if (r1.left < r2.right && r1.right > r2.left && r1.top < r2.bottom && r1.bottom > r2.top) {
      col = true;
    }
    return {
      col: col,
      right: r1.right > r2.left,
      left: r1.left > r2.right,
      bottom: r1.bottom > r2.bottom,
      top: r1.top > r2.top
    };
  }
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.helper.data("prev-pos", getObjectPos(ui.helper));
    },
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var oPrevPos = ui.helper.data("prev-pos");
      var oPos = getObjectPos(ui.helper);
      console.log(oPrevPos, oPos);
      log(oPos);
      $("#containment-wrapper .no-drag").each(function(ind, el) {
        var c = collision(ui.helper, $(el));
        var col = c.col;
        var side;
        if (col) {
          switch (true) {
            case c.top:
              side = "top";
              break;
            case c.left:
              side = "left";
              break;
            case c.bottom:
              side = "bottom";
              break;
            case c.right:
              side = "right";
              break;
          }
          console.log("Collision: " + col, side, c);
          switch (side) {
            case "left":
            case "right":
              ui.position.left = oPrevPos.left
              break;
            case "top":
            case "bottom":
              ui.position.top = oPrevPos.top
              break;
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Collision: " + c.col, c);
          ui.helper.data("prev-pos", oPos);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #CCC;
}

#containment-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#containment-wrapper .no-drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  top: 168px;
  left: 318px;
  position: absolute;
}

.output {
  margin-top: -2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="containment-wrapper">
  <div id="draggable" class="draggable">
  </div>
  <div class="no-drag">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="log" class="output"></div>
```

This is a very basic example using some 2D Collision Detection. It's not great and could use improvement, yet you can see where to start.

Hope this helps.