# Jquery How to use .live on draggable

Tags: jquery

I am using dragabble method from jquery ui. How to apply live() on draggable.

```
$("#image").draggable({ containment: [10, 150, 0, 0], scroll: false});
```

What I tried is this

```
$("#image").live("draggable", function () {
.draggable({ containment: [10, 150, 0, 0], scroll: false});
```

But this is not working.

Thanks

Comment: You mean [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).  [`.live()` has been removed as of jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: See this sample discussion http://stackoverflow.com/a/3349395/1193035

Comment: FYI, .live() is deprecated. Check out .on() instead (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: If you are trying to apply a plugin to dynamic elements, it won't work. there must be an event involved.

Comment: If you are adding the elements yourself, you should convert them to draggable as soon as they're added.

Comment: @Blazemonger: .live() is working but when I move the image, image vanishes. This is a example http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hMmbK/2/. I am using .live because in actual code image gets inserted dynamically. This is, how I am using  $('#imgage').live('mouseover',function(){

Comment: I don't see any `live()`-like functionality in your fiddle.

Comment: @Blazemonger:Can you see my comment, I have detailed explained I am using that in my code above jsfiddle is an example. can you tell me, how to convert an element into dragable.

Comment: Here is your fiddle now working. Do you see how you were setting the css width/height constraints on the div, not the img and how that was affecting your code? http://jsfiddle.net/vUzmG/

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble:Please read my above comment.

Comment: Aside from sitting at your desk and writing your code for you, I am not sure how much more I can help you. I corrected your fiddle for you and gave you an answer below, you should be able to work it out from here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly as an FYI, live is deprecated, you should be using .on() as the comments above state.

Secondly, you won't be able to do what you need to do with either scenario as those events aren't baked into on(). Therefore the way that I would approach it is to perform your event attachment inside a function:

```
function doDraggable() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: [0, finalHeight, 0, 0], scroll: false});
}
```

Then initialise it when the document is ready and also whenever ajax completes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    doDraggable();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    doDraggable();
});
```

You can be more specific than the document selector using the ajaxComplete event so that it doesn't fire for *every* ajax event, but you get my drift...

Comment: What if he's adding elements without AJAX?

Comment: Then the document.ready should cover it. Or do you mean performing ajax outside of jQuery? If so, he will need to attach callbacks to those specific ajax calls to reinitialise the attachments.

Comment: I mean adding elements to the DOM in response to a user event, such as clicking a button, simply through `$('body').append('div')` or something like that.

Comment: I see. Simply calling the function after updating the DOM would do it, right?

Comment: @Blazemonger:Can you see my comment. How do I convert them to dragable ?

Comment: By recalling .draggable on the necessary elements you have added, after they hit the DOM. Live() will work, but as we're all saying, it's deprecated. Use .on() or your code will one day simply stop working when you update jQuery.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble:Thanks for taking time to answer my question but your answer is not working.

Comment: Okay, one last try... once you have added the elements to the DOM, run this line of code again: $("#image").draggable({ containment: [0, finalHeight, 0, 0], scroll: false});

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble:You are confusing me.

Comment: If this is confusing, I would suggest that you go back to basics with jQuery as the concepts presented here are relatively simple. There are thousands of tutorials on the web. You may wish to start here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials focus on event attachments and DOM manipulation. This is also useful: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/