# How to Integrate jQuery Ui Draggable with Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

I want to use jquery ui draggable with Repeater. So It will work like when I click the button the draggable will clone with the id. So far it is done that way but the problem is the clone draggable box are not moving.

Please view...

[jQuery Ui Draggable with Repeater](http://wpgamechanger.com/ui/)

I want your very best suggestion the clone Draggable box can be Draggable as well, I can get different id of each boxes...

Comment: Are you making elements draggable by id? I suggest you do it by class

Answer (score 0):

### [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gE5Zr/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="red" class="drag"></div>
<br/>
<div id="forClones"></div>
<input type="button" id="clone" value="clone" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Draggable();
});

function Draggable() {
    $('.drag').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        containment: 'document'
    });
}

$('#clone').click(function () {
    var clone = $('#red').clone().attr('class', 'drag');
    $('#forClones').append(clone);
    Draggable();
});
```

With a bit help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15909152/2260614)